# Kotlin: C-like pre-processor macros?

Tags: kotlin

(Kotlin newbie here) I have dozens, if not hundreds, of places in my code where this line repeats:

```
EventBusProvider.getCurrentBus().offer(EventBusAction.DisplayHypo(something))
```

This line, and others like it, litter the code and make it unreadable IMHO. Good 'ole C enabled me to state:

```
#def SHOW_HYPO() EventBusProvider.getCurrentBus().offer(EventBusAction.DisplayHypo()
```

and voila, succinct and readable code from here on, and a side bonus: just one spot to change things.

Does Kotlin have something like this?  Thank you!

Comment: No there isn't anything like that. You can simply define a function, which saves as much typing.

Comment: An inline function would be very similar in behavior but a standard function should be sufficient.